# Unresolved imports in 'Smile' machine learning library

Tags: scala, machine-learning, smile

The following import does not resolve.

```
import smile.data.{Attribute, AttributeDataset, NumericAttribute}
```

Any idea on this if those attributes were removed from new Smile version 3.0.0 ?

I am using Scala 2.13.10.

How to translate the following code to Smile v3.0.0 ?

```
import smile.clustering.KMeans
import smile.data.{AttributeDataset, NumericAttribute}
import smile.read
import smile.write

// Load the data into a Smile AttributeDataset
val data: AttributeDataset = read.csv("data.csv", header = true)

// Split the data into two equal parts
val (data1, data2) = data.split(0.5)

// Train a k-means clustering model on the first part of the data
val model1 = KMeans.fit(data1.x(), 3)

// Train another k-means clustering model on the second part of the data
val model2 = KMeans.fit(data2.x(), 3)
```

Comment: https://github.com/haifengl/smile/issues/734

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for me even in Smile 1.5.3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/3aL104b4Rn6U6xK21GGosA What was the version where it worked for you?

Comment: In 3.0.0 `read.csv` returns `smile.data.DataFrame` instead of `smile.data.AttributeDataset` https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/master/base/src/main/java/smile/data/DataFrame.java https://haifengl.github.io/api/java/smile/data/DataFrame.html

Comment: For `read.csv` example see the section "Delimited Text and CSV" at the page https://haifengl.github.io/data.html

Comment: I never worked on that code @Dmytro, I asked chatGPT to generate that for me. :)

Comment: So it's not surprising that it's not working. You can try to ask it to translate the code into 3.0.0 and instead of not working code in 1.5.3 you'll have not working code in 3.0.0 :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned *"NOTE: While the above text focuses on answers, because that's where we're experiencing the largest volume of such content, the ban applies to all content on Stack Overflow, except each user's profile content (e.g. your "About me" text)."*

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/124ocqh/scala_and_chatgpt/

Answer (score 0):

The classes `smile.data.{Attribute, AttributeDataset, NumericAttribute}` existed till Smile 1.5.3 (Scala 2.10.x-2.12.x)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.haifengl/smile-scala

They were removed in Smile 2.0.0 (Nov 22, 2019)

https://github.com/haifengl/smile/commit/07c5d2507d6ee8bd1dd68202fdbb323dada91a2f (`StructType` seems to replace `Attribute[]`)

https://github.com/haifengl/smile/releases/tag/v2.0.0

> - Fully redesigned API. It is leaner, simpler and even more friendly.

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro and can you please point the examples with new Smile version 3.0.0 ?

Comment: How to translate the below code into Smile 3.0.0, completely stuck!

import smile.clustering.KMeans
import smile.data.{AttributeDataset, NumericAttribute}
import smile.read
import smile.write

// Load the data into a Smile AttributeDataset
val data: AttributeDataset = read.csv("data.csv", header = true)

// Split the data into two equal parts
val (data1, data2) = data.split(0.5)

// Train a k-means clustering model on the first part of the data
val model1 = KMeans.fit(data1.x(), 3)

Comment: @PainPoints Please don't write long code samples in comments. Comments are not for that. Please add your code to the question or start a new one with the code (well formatted).